# Links table on multiple publishing targets out of sync

Tags: links

We have set up 2 publishing targets (web and web2).  The web items tables are in sync with the same number of items and the items match when comparing. The problem is we are seeing the links tables between the 2 out of sync.  The numbers do not match?  I have noticed this using our custom config, I have also set up a minimal site from a vanilla SC deployment with the only config change being a second publishing target. After creating some templates and pages and publishing I can see the links table is out of sync even though the items including the newly created / published items match. Has anyone come across this before.  Is it something to be concerned about or is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If your both targets are identical, then it should match ideally. I would advice you to try following -

- Republish site on both targets
- Rebuild indexes
- Rebuild Link databases

Make sure to do this sequentially so not to miss out any probability.
After this you link databases should match for both targets.

And even if it doesn't, I dont feel that this is concerning. Generally we do not peep into these activities and let framework handle it.
I would only extend my investigation if I face any problem.

Hope this helps !